# How to modify Rails path names dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My `params[:type]` equals `item` (singular)

I need to send the user to

```
items_path(name: params[:name])
```

I need to pluralize the `params[:type]` part of the path and merge it with my view to get my link right, and I'm struggling to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. For unconditional pluralization you can do this:

```
plural = params[:type].pluralize # => 'items'
route_method = "#{plural}_path" # => 'items_path'
public_send(route_method, name: params[:name])
```

But it doesn't seem a very safe solution to me. Taking user input and executing it like that always rings a bell in my head. Perhaps, some whitelisting would be better (more readable too)

```
path = case params[:type]
  when 'item'
    items_path(name: params[:name])
  when 'foobar'
    foobars_path
  else
    fail 'Unknown type'
end
```